# Error: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am getting a cast error using the variable RockElem. The variable is defined in a class with other variables which are integers. This variable is defined as const.

```
    if(resistivitySolve)
        fileName << "_resist";
    else if(dynamic_cast< const Water* >(fluid) != 0)
        fileName << "_water";
    else
        fileName << "_oil";

    fileName << "_sw_" << waterSat*100.0;

    sort(m_throatConductances.begin(), m_throatConductances.end(), throatIndexCompare());
    pair<const RockElem*, double> dummy(0, 0.0);
    int idx(-99);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_throatConductances.size(); ++i)
    {
        int tmp(m_throatConductances[i].first->orenIndex());
        if(tmp == idx) m_throatConductances[i] = dummy;
        idx = tmp;
    }
```

The error i get is 
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const RockElem *'
1>          Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

---

The error is with this part of the class- using a const before the term RockElem*

```
       [
          _Ty1=const RockElem *,
          _Ty2=double,
          _Ty=int,
          _Other1=int,
          _Other2=double
       ]
```

see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base<_Ty,double>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&)' being compiled

---

The line of code using this is

```
           pair<RockElem*, double> dummy(0, 0.0);
```

Is this not set properly?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: Change it to `dummy(nullptr, 0.0)` or to `dummy {}`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Does C++11 change the rules so that a literal zero no longer converts to a pointer type? That would break a huge amount of code.

Comment: @MarkB: No, but the constructors of `pair` have changed. It's still a bit weird that this should be an error, but compounding the volatile nature of `pair` in the standard and MSVC, who knows...

Answer (score 1):

The error message

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const
>   RockElem *' 1>

is clear enough. You are trying to convert an object of an integral type to pointer RockElem *. Are you sure you want to do this? If so then follow the advice of the compiler you gave in the error message.